# Unable to install the python 3.8.5 version in nginx docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nginx

I am trying to install the python version 3.8.5 on the base nginx image on the Dockerfile and getting the error message. Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        make \
        gcc \
        xxd \
        curl \
        libcap2-bin \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get clean

RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tgz \
    && tar -xvf Python-3.8.5.tgz && cd Python-3.8.5 \
    && ./configure --enable-shared \
    && make \
    && make test \
    && make install
```

Output:

```
FAILED (errors=1, skipped=94)
tests failed again:
test_asyncio test_socket
```

Comment: Can you build a separate image `FROM python:3.8`, without Nginx?  Or use a prepackaged version of Python without building it from source?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze for your comments. I am able to install the python3 version of 3.7.3 without any issues but not sure why it is not allowing me to install the python v3.8.5. Do you have any idea?